# Project referencing error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class-library

I have an ASP.NET application (presentation layer) that references a VB.NET class library (Business Logic Layer), which references another VB.NET class library (Data Logic Layer).

When I step through the code in the code behind files I am now seeing an error:

> Could not load type 'DataLogicLayer.classname' from assembly
>   'DataLogicLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.":"DataLogicLayer.classname"}System.Exception

ClassName is from the Data Logic Layer. I am not sure how to troubleshoort this error.

(I have checked that the assemblies appear in the BIN folders.)

Comment: Try clearing out all of the DLL's by deleting them, then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a reference to an old assembly in the web.config of the web application.  Removing the assembly reference resolved the problem.